# error: cannot spawn git: Function not implemented

Tags: windows, git, cmd

Я на хероку хочу закинуть своего бота и вот когда пишу

```
 git push heroku master
```

выводит

```
 error: cannot spawn git: Function not implemented
```

Как это решить ?

Версия гит 2.16.1, ОС--Windows7 x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это баг в свежем обновлении дистрибутива, проявляется на 2.16.1 и 2.16.2

Об этом же [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48601101/5752652) коллеги на en so и уже появлся [issue на гитхабе](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1475).

Либо ждите исправления, либо временно [установите более раннюю](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) версию.

Если есть аккаунт на гитхаб – можете в том issue указать, что проблема воспроизводится не только на Windows Server 2008, но и на вашей Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @РомаБойко Вышла версия 2.16.3 (не могу найти changelog, но вижу, что баг на гитхабе закрыт), можете посмотреть - ошибка исчезла?

Comment: Исчезла, больше не проявляется. Только не 2.16.3, а 2.16.1.3.

Comment: Лучше даже 2.16.1.4 (только что вышла), тогда и TortoiseGit не будет ругаться.

Comment: @AK на версии 2.8.1.windows.1 все работает